# Repeating unique column names

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 9 columns (V1, V2....V9). I'd like to label each column: Cat_1, Mouse_1, Chicken_1, repeating these names with an unique ID number separated by "_". For example, starting on the fourth column - Cat_2, Mouse_2, Chicken_2 and so on. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `outer`.

```
names(d) <- outer(c("cat", "mouse", "chicken"), 1:3, paste, sep="_")
d
#   cat_1 mouse_1 chicken_1 cat_2 mouse_2 chicken_2 cat_3 mouse_3 chicken_3
# 1     0       0         0     0       0         0     0       0         0
# 2     0       0         0     0       0         0     0       0         0
# 3     0       0         0     0       0         0     0       0         0
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(0, 3, 9))
```

Comment: How can this be applied to rows as well?

Comment: @logananthony510 Using `rownames()` instead of `names()`. For `names()` you could also write `colnames()` (which also works on matrices).

Answer (score 1):

We can create a grouping index with `gl`, use `paste` to join the vector of animal names and assign it back to dataset

```
names(df1) <- paste0(c("Cat_", "Mouse_", "Chicken_"), 
           as.integer(gl(ncol(df1), 3, ncol(df1))))
```

output

```
df1
#  Cat_1 Mouse_1 Chicken_1 Cat_2 Mouse_2 Chicken_2 Cat_3 Mouse_3 Chicken_3
#1     7       3         9     8       8         1     3       7         2
#2     3       8         8     1       2         5     1       1         4
#3     8       6         7     5       1         4     3       6         3
#4     7       9         8     5       5         6     8       7         6
#5     2       4         1     5       2         6     6       1         3
```

---

or another option is `make.unique` with `rep`

```
names(df1) <- make.unique(rep(c("Cat", "Mouse", "Chicken"), 
               length.out = ncol(df1)))
```

NOTE: Both solutions work for any number of columns

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 9 *5, replace = TRUE), ncol = 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option is using `expand.grid` + `paste`

```
setNames(df,do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(c("cat", "mouse", "chicken"), 1:3), sep = "_")))
```